# Can I run a regression of $ y$ on $ z$ if $y(x(z))$?

Tags: regression

I have a question regarding my regression analysis. I want to regress y (
output in construction) on z (temperature deviation from baseline). The temperature deviation is going to lead to x (less hours worked) which is going to influence y (construction output).
So basically I am stating that $y(x(z)).$ Can I then directly regress $y $ on $z$? In order to obtain the effect of temperature deviation on construction output.

Comment: Regression makes no assumptions about *how* one variable might depend on another.

Comment: What you are describing sure sounds like mediation analysis. There are many threads on that here. If that's not what you want, please clarify.

Comment: If you are using linear regression, then you are assuming linear relationships at least over the range of values you are considering.  This may break down: if the temperature is so high or so low that your model suggests an negative number of hours worked or more hours than there are in a day, then it presumably does not reflect reality, but you may not be considering such extreme cases

Comment: This sounds like you are interested in [tag:causal-inference].